# 8bit sRGB and OpenGL confusion

Tags: opengl, srgb

I would like to ask a clarification about the sRGB color space and its 8bit per channel representation in OpenGL. After digging in the subject, I found out that storing images in sRGB is just made to compensate the opposite gamma operation done by the monitor which "imitates" what the old CTR did by nature for compatibility reasons. The fact that the human eye has a similiar non linear response is just a coincidence and has nothing to do with gamma correction (as many confusing articles claim) as the output will be [linear again anyway](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53725/what-is-the-purpose-of-gamma-correction-in-todays-screens-and-how-does-it-relat).

Assuming that this understanding is right, in OpenGL we have the GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 format for textures, which has 8bit per channel. However since the range of 0~255 is the same as a linear RGB texture, does this mean that to convert a linear 8bit per channel texture to sRGB the color values remain unchanged and a simple "flag" tells OpenGL: Look this 0~255 range is not linear so interpret them as a curve?
What about sRGB 16bit per channel images (ex. 16bit PNGs) ?

Answer (score 4):

The range is the same. [The *values* are not](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut12%20Monitors%20and%20Gamma.html).

Your linear values before storing are floating-point. So they have greater precision than an 8-bit-per-channel format.

If you store them in a linearRGB image, you're taking the input range [0, 1] and evenly mapping them to [0, 255].

But if you do sRGB conversion, then you're taking the [0, 1] range and mapping them to [0, 255] via a non-linear gamma mapping of approximately 2.2. While this non-linear mapping does not magically create more values, what it does do is effectively give you more precision in the higher parts of the range than the lower parts.

In sRGB conversion, values in the input range [0.5, 1] are mapped to [56, 255]. That's over 75% of the output range that's covered by 50% of the input range. This gives you a better representation of the larger values in your input.

A linear mapping loses precision evenly. The sRGB mapping loses more precision in the darker areas than the lighter. Or to put it another way, it *preserves* more precision in the lighter areas than the linear mapping.

For a memory vs. visual quality tradeoff, sRGB comes out better overall than linearRGB 8-bit-per-channel.

> However since the range of 0~255 is the same as a linear RGB texture, does this mean that to convert a linear 8bit per channel texture to sRGB the color values remain unchanged and a simple "flag" tells OpenGL: Look this 0~255 range is not linear so interpret them as a curve?

It depends on what operation you're talking about.

An sRGB texture is a texture that stores its RGB information in the sRGB colorspace. However, shader operations are assumed to want data in the linearRGB colorspace, not sRGB. So [using an sRGB format means that texture fetches will *convert* the pixels they read from sRGB to linearRGB](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#sRGB_colorspace).

Writes from a fragment shader to an FBO-attached image using an sRGB format may or may not perform conversion. Here, conversion has to be explicitly enabled with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB`. The idea being that some operations will generate values in the sRGB colorspace (GUIs, for example. Most images were created in the sRGB colorspace), while others will generate values in linearRGB (normal rendering). So you have an option to turn on or off conversion.

The conversion also allows blending to [read sRGB destination pixels, convert them to linear, blend with the incoming linearRGB values, and then convert them back to sRGB for writing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Source.2C_Destination.2C_and_the_buffer).

Uploads to and downloads from an sRGB image will write and read the pixel values in the sRGB colorspace directly.

> What about sRGB 16bit per channel images (ex. 16bit PNGs) ?

What about them? OpenGL has no 16-bit-per-channel sRGB formats.

sRGB conversion is typically done via a 256-entry table lookup. For every sRGB value, there is a pre-computed linear one.

So, just like any other case where an image format offers something that OpenGL doesn't match, you'll have to manually convert them.

Answer (score 1):

### Gamma is Good

> *I found out that storing images in sRGB is just made to compensate the opposite gamma operation done by the monitor...the fact that the human eye has a similiar non linear response is just a coincidence and has nothing to do with gamma correction ... **Assuming that this understanding is right**,*

That understanding is not correct. Storing images with a gamma curve is necessary to increase the data density in dark areas for perceptual reasons. Without gamma, you would need 12 bits for linear for the same image fidelity you get with 8 bits and a gamma curve.

Old school TVs could have been designed to use a linearized signal, but in fact the design techniques of the day *increased* gamma from the theoretical 1.5 to the commonly used 2.4. As a function of system design the use of gamma reduced the perception of noise in the broadcast signal.

A gamma-type of transfer curve makes the most of a limited bandwidth by weighting the available bandwidth per human non-linear visual perception.

### OPENGL

As for your question, If the internal format parameter is GL_SRGB, GL_SRGB8, GL_SRGB_ALPHA, or GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, ***the texture is treated as if the red, green, or blue components are encoded in the sRGB color space.***

This means that the values in the image are assumed to be gamma-encoded values as opposed to GL_RGB8 which are assumed to be linear.

> *However since the range of 0~255 is the same as a linear RGB texture, does this mean that to convert a linear 8bit per channel texture to sRGB the color values remain unchanged and a simple "flag" tells OpenGL: Look this 0~255 range is not linear so interpret them as a curve? What about sRGB 16bit per channel images (ex. 16bit PNGs) ?*

The range or bit depth has nothing at all to do with a gamma curve being used or not.

An *image* needs gamma for perceptual reasons. A linear texture map or bump map does not. If you use the GL_SRGB8 tag on a linear bump map, then GL will use sRGB gamma on that linear data which you do NOT want to do - that is it will apply a power curve of approximately 2.2 to linear 1.0 values, and this is not want you want, unless your bump map IS an image with a gamma curve.

The sRGB tag is there so that when you have an sRGB image which has the color values encoded with a ~1/2.2 curve, those values become linearized.